# Alternative for display: contents in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I want to display error message below the registration form. To do so I used `display: contents` but it turns out it doesn't work in Safari. Is there any alternative to do so?

With `display: contents` in Chrome I have desired result like this with css below:
https://monosnap.com/file/hApBoD6kJ7eBNnuNMcFAvaBhckodUw

```
~ .bank-employees-users-registration__registrations-input--invalid-msg {
  display: contents;
  position: absolute;
```

When I changed it to `display: inline-block` and add some `padding` and `margin` 
https://monosnap.com/file/SLQgG4uxpgEnHhk9o6GHeJrGKBes51

```
~ .bank-employees-users-registration__registrations-input--invalid-msg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: .6rem;
  margin-top: -.5;
```

Any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: put position `relative`instead `absolute`or give the more space to the inputs

Comment: Thanks @LuísP.A. ! it works even without padding and margin.